# Continue downloading after a network glitch - Kali

Tags: apt, kali-linux

Say there's a dependency, 100MB in size, of any package which is to be downloaded using `apt-get` and after downloading 56MB of it the connection goes down. On passing the command to install again, Kali starts downloading it from the beginning while BackBox, which I used to use earlier, is configured to download it from 56MB onwards. I wonder if Kali can be configured to do the same. I need it to be so as I have a very unstable network connection.

Comment: you might want to see [THIS THREAD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425502/how-do-i-continue-configuration-if-apt-get-was-interrupted)

Comment: @MelBurslan : That's for the case when you get an error while installation and not downloading. I want something like caching the downloaded file immediately during it's download, even a part of that file.

Comment: As far as I remember, apt-get does this. But it can only do it if the server supports it, which is not always the case. Try a different mirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APT *does* continue downloading after a network glitch. This is true on any distribution that uses it, BackBox and Kali alike.

Resuming a download depends on the cooperation of the server. Some web servers don't recognize the `Range:` HTTP header and always send the whole file. If your interrupted downloads always restart from the beginning, it means that you're downloading from a server that doesn't support downloading part of a file. Look for a different mirror that supports the `Range:` header.